# silverstripe RestfulServer Module - get related records with all attributes

Tags: rest, content-management-system, silverstripe

Using the Restful Server Module I do this operation:

`GET /api/v1/(ClassName)?(Field)=(Val)&(Field)=(Val)` - searches for matching database records

The api should get the urls of all images related to a certain product like this:
http://domain.com/api/v1/Product?ArticleID=myID

unfortunately the returned XML does not show the full information of the ProductImages. just the attributes href and id. 
here the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayList totalSize="1">
<Product href="http://domain.com/api/v1/Product/9.xml">
<ArticleID>myID</ArticleID>
<ID>9</ID>
<ProductImages linktype="has_many" href="http://domain.com/api/v1/Product/9/ProductImages.xml">
<ProductImage href="http://domain.com/api/v1/ProductImage/265.xml" id="265"/>
<ProductImage href="http://domain.com/api/v1/ProductImage/268.xml" id="268"/>
<ProductImage href="http://domain.com/api/v1/ProductImage/271.xml" id="271"/>
</ProductImages>
</Product>
</ArrayList>
```

ProductImage has much more attributes actually which are not displayed in the xml. How to make them visible? I can see all ProductImage Attributes when doing e.g. this:
http://domain.com/api/v1/Product/9/ProductImages

I use curl to load the urls.
In the worst case I think I have to take the ProductImage urls from the XML (e.g. http://domain.com/api/v1/ProductImage/271.xml) and do multiple calls.

many thx for any help,
florian

Comment: status: I´m doing now multiple calls. But it seems to be a slow solution :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the `relationDepth` inside `RestfulServer`. You can do that by passing in the `relationdepth` query string parameter.

As an aside, the reason it works like this is to keep the load low on the server by not having to instantiate all the image objects. It also means bandwidth is slightly lower too.

Comment: hi! relationdepth does not help. i think it´s needed to show more deep level of relations. in my case ProductImages show up already but still with just the id and href attributes. there are much more.

Comment: at the moment I could help myself by adding public getter functions to product. as described here: http://www.silverstripe.org/dataobjectmanager-module-forum/show/12526
for example I added a public getter which returns a comma separated string containing all related ProductImage urls. works fine.